# Dealing with Diffstat output on the terminal

Tags: python, scripting

Here is the output when I did a diffstat on the terminal. What is the best way to just get the numbers 133 and 85 into two columns into a CSV file? Thanks.

```
README.md  |   88 +++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
home.html  |only
index.html |  130 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------
libraries  |only
4 files changed, 133 insertions(+), 85 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you write the diff to a file `diff.txt` like this:

```
README.md  |   88 +++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
home.html  |only
index.html |  130 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------
libraries  |only
4 files changed, 133 insertions(+), 85 deletions(-)
```

And have a `.csv` file with these headers:

```
insertions,deletions
```

Then this could work:

```py
import re, csv

s = None

with open("diff.txt", mode="r") as diff_file:
    s = diff_file.readlines().pop()

regex = r"(?P<insertions>\d*) insertions\(\+\), (?P<deletions>\d*) deletions.*"
pattern = re.compile(regex)

match = pattern.search(s)

with open("diffs.csv", mode="a", newline="") as diffs_csv:
    fieldnames = ['insertions', 'deletions']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(diffs_csv, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerow(match.groupdict())
```

Here's that on my machine:

```sh
➜  diffstat ls
diffs.csv  diff.txt  main.py
➜  diffstat cat diffs.csv
insertions,deletions
➜  diffstat cat diff.txt
README.md  |   88 +++++++++++++++++++++--------------------
home.html  |only
index.html |  130 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------
libraries  |only
4 files changed, 133 insertions(+), 85 deletions(-)
➜  diffstat python main.py
➜  diffstat cat diffs.csv
insertions,deletions
133,85
```

You can create the `diff.txt` file and run the script like this:

```sh
git diff --stat > diff.txt & python main.py
```

Comment: I like your regex. Thanks !